# Get all HTML comments on website with html simple dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I've tried to grab all the comments from a website (The text between `<!--` and `-->`), but without luck.

Here is my current code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('THE URL');
foreach($html->find('comment') as $element)
    echo $element->plaintext;
```

Anyone have any ideas how to grab the comments, at the moment it's only giving me a blank page

Comment: Did you tried to print `$html`'s value before foreach to make sure that it is loaded successfully?

Comment: Yes, then I get a big array when i print_r the output

Comment: It seems it works fine, but as you are doing `echo` and it outputs html comment, browser doesn't show it. Try to do `var_dump($element->plaintext);` to make sure that there is a value.

Comment: Don't get any output either with var_dum

Answer (score 1):

I know `regex` is not supposed to parse HTML, but `<!--(.*?)-->` you can use a similar `regex` to find and fetch the comments...

Comment: Yes comments are easily parsable with regex